# Role based registration in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, registration

I have a requirement to register users in two different categories like Employer and Job seeker. So I need two separate registration page for two type of users. I couldn't find any suitable plugin for that. and each user will get assigned their roles depending the page submission. If an Employer is logged in they have to post their jobs and their informations, can view the applications against their posted jobs, and if a job seeker gets logged in they have the access to view the jobs, apply against jobs, can read reviews about their applications etc. I am a newbie to wordpress. I need a guidance regarding this.